# Create matrix table using SQL server Business Intelligence reporting services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, business-intelligence

I have a complex SQL query that returns count values for a series of analysis processes. The category '889' is further split into subcategories that are determined by a join of two tables. Query is below:

```
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE (
            ordnum INT,
            fldrinit VARCHAR(8),
            giscode VARCHAR(15),
            day INT null)

DECLARE @curmonth int
SET @curmonth = 6
INSERT INTO @tbl

select o.ordnum, o.FldrInit, a.GisCode, @curmonth
from tod..CurrentOrders as o
left join
tod..addr as a 
on o.RecNumAddr = a.RecNumAddr
inner join
tod..CustInfo as c
on o.CustNum = c.CustNum

where datepart(year, o.OrdDte) = '2014'
and datepart(month, o.OrdDte) = '6'
and o.OrdStat = 'c'
and o.CustNum not in ('1000045506', '1000126887', '1000132094', '1000149661', '1000163278')
and o.OrdType not like '%[ABCEGIMNQSUY]%'
and o.OrdType not like 'H%'
and o.FldrInit not in ('892', '555', '909', '988', '989', '996', '895', '1882', '1885', '1886', '1889', '1898', '1899', '1900', '1901', '1902', 'ADD')
and c.CustNme not like '%TEST%'

SELECT
(SELECT count(*) as [883] from @tbl where fldrinit = '883') as [883],
(SELECT count(*) as [885] from @tbl where fldrinit = '885') as [885],
(SELECT count(*) as [886] from @tbl where fldrinit = '886') as [886],
(SELECT count(*) as [887] from @tbl where fldrinit = '887') as [887],
(SELECT count(*) as [889 Total] from @tbl where fldrinit = '889') as [889 Total],
(SELECT count(*) as [889 G1 Pt] from @tbl where fldrinit = '889' 
    AND giscode like 'hap%'
    or giscode like 'sap%') as [889 G1 Pt],
(SELECT count(*) as [889 G1 Road] from @tbl where fldrinit = '889'
    AND giscode like 'has%'
    or giscode like 'sas%') as [889 G1 Road],
(SELECT count(*) as [889 Parcelstream Pt] from @tbl where fldrinit = '889'
    and giscode like 'A????') as [889 Parcelstream Pt],
(SELECT count(*) as [889 Parcelstream Rd] from @tbl where fldrinit = '889'
    and giscode like 'R????') as [889 Parcelstream Rd],
(SELECT count(*) as [900] from @tbl where fldrinit = '900') as [900],
(SELECT count(*) as [902] from @tbl where fldrinit = '902') as [902],
(SELECT count(*) as [Manual] from @tbl where fldrinit not in ('883', '885', '886', '887', '889', '900', '902')) as [Manual],
(SELECT count(*) as [Grand Total] from @tbl) as [Grand Total];
```

First, the query builder does not accept a "DECLARE" statement. I can build individual expressions within the matrix for every process except 889 using the first portion of the query (without the DECLARE or SELECT COUNT(*), but I need everything for 889. Any hints? Very new to this software.

Comment: Have you tried using `MONTH(GETDATE())` in place of `@curmonth`?

Comment: I have just replaced it with an integer for right now because I can't declare anything within the query builder.

Comment: what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: SQL 2012, if that is what you're asking.